# Appcenter push: dynamic navigation based on custom data

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, visual-studio-app-center

I'm wondering if I could get some help using AppCenter push in my Xamarin Forms app that targets Android & iOS.

Essentially, I've followed the instructions and I'm able to see the push notifications in my testing on Android. I understand that there are different behaviors between foreground and background notifications and have stepped through via the debugger when the PushNotificationReceived event happens..

The issue I'm having is I cannot find a reliable way to isolate when a user is entering the app because they tapped on a notification when the app is not loaded.

In my App.xaml.cs, I have the following:

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Push.PushNotificationReceived += Push_PushNotificationReceived;


            AppCenter.Start("ios={ios ID}" +
                  "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
                  "android={android ID}",
                  typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Push));

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Splash"); // this is my splash screen that shows

        }

private async void Push_PushNotificationReceived(object sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CustomData != null)
            {
                if (e.CustomData.ContainsKey("roundId"))
                {
                    string roundId = e.CustomData["roundId"];
                   //I want to navigate directly to this UI 
                    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"IconNavigationPage/HomeView/Round?roundId={roundId}");
                }
            }
        }
```

So, as you can see, under normal circumstances, the app will load the Splash view which does some loading, and redirects to a home view. When the notification is received and the user has the app running in the background, on Android, it's working fine. I changed my launch mode to SingleTop and added the following to my MainActivity.cs

```
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Android.Content.Intent intent)
            {
                base.OnNewIntent(intent);
                Push.CheckLaunchedFromNotification(this, intent);
            }
```

The issue is, when the app is not running in the background, and I tap the notification, the Splash screen navigation call is called, then my navigation call in the PushNotificationReceived event. This essentially causes the app to load the UI that is defined in the event, for a second, then Splash UI redirects happen. This is due to the fact that OnInitialize() gets ran when the app is loaded from the Tap of the notification, when the app is not running in the background.

I have experimented in trying to implement the PushNotificationReceived event handler in the Android MainActivity.cs file, and I do see that this fires before the same PushNotificationReceived event handlers in the Shared project. Unfortunately it runs after the call to the LoadApplication, so my shared project's OnInitialize() gets fired first (which has that navigation call to Splash)

I guess what I'm looking for is some guidance, or maybe a point to a tutorial, on how I can accomplish notifying the Shared project's OnInitialize not to do the standard navigation to Splash, but rather do the navigation necessary for the Push Notification instead. I've search high and low, but all of tutorials / docs simply do a debug write to console proving that that the custom data that was passed is there, which I too can see, I cannot find anything that handles real-world use cases of a viable workflow to control navigation based on the tap of a notification.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: Can't we just simply use a Flag that get set when you click on Notification, then In your initialize code you check for the Flag to see if you need to open splash!

Comment: Unfortunately the event handler which handles push notifications fires after the main method on application load which does the initial redirect. That's what I found anyway, I did try to isolate the method with a Boolean variable to bypass the initial navigation, however the bullion is not settle after unfortunately. I think the key is in the Android or iOS main activity, because those event handlers happened before, but I've not found a way to discern if a push notification happened and also how to pass that over to the PCL project.

Comment: could you use Splash page as the launcher page,dont navigation splash in the App.xaml.cs,only navigation your custom page in it

Comment: Not sure how that'll help since I'd be in the same position of not knowing if the originating action of loading the app came from the push notification or not.   The issue is I have no way of knowing...

Comment: if you set Splash page as the launcher page,it means app will display splash page first,then navigation your receive custom page when your app is not running in the back ground